# How to find "file-release" in OS X El Capitan 10.11.6?

Tags: macos, install, filesystem

I can not find file-release through command line on OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6. On my virtual machine in Ubuntu I can do "ls /etc/*release" and it shows me two files with all needed information:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.0 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.0"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.0 (Maipo)"
```

No idea how to find the file with release information on Mac. Please give me a hint or a hint how to search it?

Answer (score 9):

The file(s) `/etc/*release` contain OS specific informations like distribution name and version mainly [in Linux distributions](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html).

One of the purpose of the file(s) is to help software to detect the distribution type.

A file which contains similar informations doesn't really exist in OS X/macOS but can be mimicked with the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

OS=`uname -s`
REV=`uname -r`
MACH=`uname -m`
if [ "${OS}" = "Darwin" ]; then
    OIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=$'\n'
    set `sw_vers` > /dev/null
    DIST=`echo $1 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed 's/ProductName:[ ]*//'`
    VERSION=`echo $2 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed 's/ProductVersion:[ ]*//'`
    BUILD=`echo $3 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed 's/BuildVersion:[ ]*//'`
    OSSTR="${OS} ${DIST} ${REV}(SORRY_NO_PSEUDONAME ${BUILD} ${MACH})"
    IFS="$OIFS"
fi
echo ${OSSTR}
```

Executing the script in my system will yield:

```
Darwin Mac OS X 13.4.0(SORRY_NO_PSEUDONAME 13F1911 x86_64)
```

---

In OS X/macOS the file is not needed because the requirements of a software package are determined by other means:

- Info.plist in an installer app (e.g. *Install macOS Sierra.app* requires LSArchitecturePriority=x86_64 or LSMinimumSystemVersion=10.7)
- preflight scripts in an installer packages which use `sw_vers` or similar commands to determine the OS version.

Answer (score 6):

Setting aside that linux has a different release structure than macOS - you can use the native tool and files to catalog macOS versions for all OS X prior to 10.12 as well:

```
 /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

And the manual page for `sw_vers` documents the above as the source for build and OS naming.

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12
BuildVersion:   16A323
```

Also, the javascript documentation seems a little more detailed if you don't need a bash / shell / command tool: https://developer.apple.com/reference/installerjs/system

Comment: Yeah, the unix core of the macOS is derived from the FreeBSD OS, not Linux. Hence the different directory structure and command. Also, `uname -mrs` will give information about the macOS kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a formal release file but there are a few utilities that allow you to query the operating system for version information.

`sw_vers` prints macOS version information and but has command line options to print just the version item you are interested in. From the man page:

```
 sw_vers
 sw_vers -productName
 sw_vers -productVersion
 sw_vers -buildVersion
```

You can use the output from the `sysctl` command to get specific version info. You can put this together to build the relevant version information that you need for your application. To get the version of macOS for your system:

```
% sysctl kern.osproductversion
kern.osproductversion: 12.3.1
```

`sysctl -a` prints all output: have a look through this for specific items you might be interested in to build a custom version print-out