# How can I identify the macOS version from the command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

After detecting a GNU/Linux system through running `uname`, [in a GNU/Linux distribution `lsb_release -a` is a good *entry level* utility you could use to [try to] find out the GNU/Linux distribution name and particular version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484696/1737973)<sup>1</sup>.

After detecting a Darwin (possibly macOS) system through running `uname`, there must be a *Different* (maybe not that much...) way to **Ask** the OS version number<sup>1</sup>. Even if it only works on macOS, it'd be useful.

This is similar to the [/etc/release for other Unix / Linux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255546/how-to-find-file-release-in-os-x-el-capitan-10-11-6), but I’d like to specifically target macOS to script a check of the version. In what way(s) is this possible?

Comment: lsb are specifically Linux tools as per https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/368245/237 As macOS is not Linux what are you looking for?

Comment: And you need to explain what you need as uname -a being arid is not helpful. Hint theis is macOS and many of us do not know what lsb etc provide.

Comment: What does `lsb_release -a` do (on a Linux system), and what exactly do you want to do with the result on macOS? Some more details on this might help to find suitable alternatives .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are some other options that you could use.

```
sysctl kern.version
kern.version: Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Sun Jun  2 20:26:31 PDT 2019; root:xnu-3789.73.50~1/RELEASE_X86_64

sysctl kern.ostype
kern.ostype: Darwin

sysctl kern.osrelease
kern.osrelease: 16.7.0

sysctl kern.osrevision
kern.osrevision: 199506
```

And as an alternative to `sw_vers`

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print:ProductName" \
                        -c "Print:ProductVersion" \
                        -c "Print:ProductBuildVersion" /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
Mac OS X
10.12.6
16G2128
```

Answer (score 28):

I don't know if all of this is imposed by Darwin, the manual page seems like it maybe is a Mac OS X (sic in my manual page as of Sep 2019) thing, but there is the awesome `sw_vers`:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   yadda yadda yadda
$ _
```

Answer (score 4):

LSB stands for "Linux Standard Base".

macOS isn't Linux, so it isn't part of the LSB project, and doesn't support LSB tools.

Comment: Actually, one of the major reasons for the LSB Specifications is that they provide a precise description of the APIs and ABIs required to run "Linux" applications *independent of* Linux. IOW, *you should not need* Linux to run an LSB-conformant Linux application, and you should not need to look at Linux to develop an LSB-conformant OS. For example, HP-UX, IBM AIX, and FreeBSD provide LSB-conformant ABIs and APIs that allow you to run LSB-conformant "Linux" applications unmodified. So, the argument that macOS doesn't support LSB because it isn't Linux is invalid, since that's actually one of …

Comment: … the purposes of the LSB: to allow Operating Systems that are not Linux to be compliant with the LSB without having to derive from or look at Linux source code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag But macOS makes no attempt to be compatible with Linux!

Comment: @JörgWMittag But that assumes that the OS authors want to be compliant and can be bothered to write what they see as unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard way - uname - defined in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) so works in all Unix systems and sopme others that provide compatibility.

Examples from my Mac mini running macOS 10.14.6

`uname -a` gives all it can

```
Darwin mini12 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Given the question you link to the full answer is possibly alter the script in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56968182/151019 The code for macOS is the same as for Solaris except change the DIST and OS values

`uname -v` prints the operating system version. (actual POSIX definition is Write the current version level of this release of the operating system implementation.)  For macOS it prints the Darwin version. The Linux man page says it prints the kernal version. (Solaris has the same definition as the macOS man page so I assume it is the version of the Solaris kernal.)

```
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
```

and `uname -r` just gives the number (POSIX definition - Write the current release level of the operating system implementation.)

```
18.7.0
```